# eTA approved denied entry to canada?

Tags: usa, canada, eta, customs-and-immigration

I'm very  concerned about visiting Canada and here is why:

I previously had a **F1 Student VISA** in the USA that was **granted** to me in 2016.So I was studying there for couple semester, but then my VISA got terminated while I was there ,because of a lack of sight on my end.The law of an US F1 visa says that in Order to be "Valid" you need to be a full time student it means to be enrolled in at least 4 classes.During one of my semester I was under-enrolled which means I was registered to 3 classes instead of 4 because there was some issue registering for one particular class.

because of that my USA visa got terminated and I just had few options either re apply for a VISA or moving back to my country I decided to leave voluntarily 3 month later, and never came back or applied for any visa ever again. I didn't get any Order to leave/deported and I don't have any ban or criminal history in the US.

on the **eTA** background question there is one question about it "Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry to, or ordered to leave Canada or any other country/territory?"

I answer No but this is tricky question for me because I never got a US Visa DENIED to me when I apply, However I was granted a  student VISA but it  got "TERMINATED' because of the issue I said

my eTA got approved months ago and it still valid and it didn't get cancelled or anything (I'm assuming that didn't count as a mistake? but I'm not 100% sure either)

I'm very confused about that and I'm a little worried that I'll be denied for my lack of sight when I was a Student in the US

Comment: So, you've been granted an eTA, and you're asking us whether you'll be denied entry? We have no idea. Border guards have wide discretion to permit or deny entry. You may be denied for reasons unconnected with your eTA, or for reasons connected with data held by the Canadian authorities which we can't possibly have access to. You have an eTA: enjoy your trip.

Comment: an ETA is no guarantee for being allowed entry, just like a visa (or indeed a passport from a country not requiring one). You can in theory be denied entry just because some border agent doesn't for example like your hairstyle (though in reality they're more professional than that).

Comment: If you’re so concerned about it, why go there?

Comment: Given that your "_USA visa got terminated and I just had few options either re apply for a VISA or moving back to my country_", does that necessarily mean that you were officially _ordered_ to leave?  You say you had an _option_ to reapply but you _chose_ to leave, so that doesn't sound like you were served with an official "Order to leave".

Comment: If a visa is terminated that's an order to leave. You can do something to reverse that order (i.e. reapply) but it's still an order to leave.

Comment: @DJClayworth I googled about "Order to leave" and what it means apparently it's when you get convicted in court by a judge to leave the country because you don't hold legal paper.It also means procedure to get deported or removed.I'm not sure but you might be right I might need to talk with a Lawyer to confirm my situation

Comment: @Ray Butterworth  in Order for me to reapply for a new  US VISA I had to go back to my country anyway and reapply for it which I choose not to do.From what I understand "Order to leave" means that I was convicted by a judge to court to leave or be removed/deported from the country which is not my case